# dpdk sanity check take strange packet with m->nb_segs only one segment but have m->next

Tags: c, dpdk

I keep receiving fragment udp packets and do reassemble two fragment packets to one, it become multi-seg packet, and then send to another NIC,
(NIC 710 port0 -> do reassembel -> NIC 710 port1 -> NIC 710 port1 recevice packets -> do fragment -> NIC 710 port0)

I receive a strange packet which only have one segment, but m-> next is not NULL.
so after pkt_len minus two times,  pkt_len become underflow,

this problem run about 5.5hours ocuur, how to prevent this problem?

platform:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
kernel version: Linux mec 4.15.0-112-generic 
DPDK version: DPDK 19.11.11 (LTS)
NIC: Intel 710
```

NIC firmware:

```
mec@mec:~$ sudo lshw -c Network | grep X710 -B10
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+
--
       version: 02
       serial: f8:f2:1e:58:9b:b0
       size: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=i40e driverversion=2.1.14-k duplex=full firmware=6.80 0x80003d73 18.8.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=fibre speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:97 memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:94018000-9401ffff memory:94100000-9417ffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+
--
       version: 02
       serial: f8:f2:1e:58:9b:b1
       size: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=i40e driverversion=2.1.14-k duplex=full firmware=6.80 0x80003d73 18.8.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=fibre speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:97 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:94010000-94017fff memory:94180000-941fffff
  *-network:2 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+
--
       version: 02
       serial: f8:f2:1e:58:9b:b2
       size: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=i40e driverversion=2.1.14-k duplex=full firmware=6.80 0x80003d73 18.8.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=fibre speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:97 memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:94008000-9400ffff memory:94200000-9427ffff
  *-network:3 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+
```

```
mec@mec:~$ sudo ethtool -i enp3s0f0
driver: i40e
version: 2.1.14-k
firmware-version: 6.80 0x80003d73 18.8.9
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

```
int rte_mbuf_check_handmade1(const struct rte_mbuf *m, int is_header,
           const char **reason)
{
    unsigned int nb_segs, pkt_len;

    if (m == NULL) {
        *reason = "mbuf is NULL";
        return -1;
    }

    /* generic checks */
    if (m->pool == NULL) {
        *reason = "bad mbuf pool";
        return -1;
    }
    if (m->buf_iova == 0) {
        *reason = "bad IO addr";
        return -1;
    }
    if (m->buf_addr == NULL) {
        *reason = "bad virt addr";
        return -1;
    }

    uint16_t cnt = rte_mbuf_refcnt_read(m);
    if ((cnt == 0) || (cnt == UINT16_MAX)) {
        *reason = "bad ref cnt";
        return -1;
    }

    /* nothing to check for sub-segments */
    if (is_header == 0)
        return 0;

    /* data_len is supposed to be not more than pkt_len */
    if (m->data_len > m->pkt_len) {
        *reason = "bad data_len";
        return -1;
    }

    nb_segs = m->nb_segs;
    pkt_len = m->pkt_len;
     uint16_t port = m->port, data_len = m->data_len, ori_nb_segs = m->nb_segs, buf_len = m->buf_len;
     uint32_t ori_pkt_len = m->pkt_len;
     uint64_t ol_flags = m->ol_flags;
     struct rte_mbuf* last_ptr;
     // os_printf("before loop: ol_flags = %"PRIu64", port = %"PRIu16", data_len = %"PRIu16", pkt_len = %"PRIu32", nb_segs = %"PRIu16", buf_len = %"PRIu16"\n", m->ol_flags, m->port, m->data_len, m->pkt_len, m->nb_segs, m->buf_len);

    do {
        if (m->data_off > m->buf_len) {
            *reason = "data offset too big in mbuf segment";
            return -1;
        }
        if (m->data_off + m->data_len > m->buf_len) {
            *reason = "data length too big in mbuf segment";
            return -1;
        }
          os_log_debug("bf loop: ol_flags = %"PRIu64", port = %"PRIu16", data_len = %"PRIu16", pkt_len = %"PRIu32", nb_segs = %"PRIu16", buf_len = %"PRIu16"\n", m->ol_flags, m->port, m->data_len, m->pkt_len, m->nb_segs, m->buf_len);
        nb_segs -= 1;
        pkt_len -= m->data_len;
          os_log_debug("in loop: ol_flags = %"PRIu64", port = %"PRIu16", data_len = %"PRIu16", pkt_len = %"PRIu32", nb_segs = %"PRIu16", buf_len = %"PRIu16"\n", m->ol_flags, m->port, m->data_len, pkt_len, nb_segs, m->buf_len);
          last_ptr = (struct rte_mbuf* )m;
    } while ((m = m->next) != NULL);
     
     if(pkt_len){
          os_printf("before loop: ol_flags = %"PRIu64", port = %"PRIu16", data_len = %"PRIu16", pkt_len = %"PRIu32", nb_segs = %"PRIu16", buf_len = %"PRIu16"\n", ol_flags, port, data_len, ori_pkt_len, ori_nb_segs, buf_len);
          os_printf("after loop: pkt_len = %"PRIu32", nb_segs = %"PRIu16"\n", pkt_len, nb_segs);
          if(last_ptr != NULL){
               os_printf("last_ptr is not NULL and addr = %p\n", last_ptr);
          } else {
               os_printf("last_ptr is NULL\n");
          }
     }
     
    if (nb_segs) {
        *reason = "bad nb_segs";
        return -1;
    }
    if (pkt_len) {
        *reason = "bad pkt_len";
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void
rte_mbuf_sanity_check_handmade1(const struct rte_mbuf *m, int is_header)
{
    const char *reason;

    if (rte_mbuf_check_handmade1(m, is_header, &reason)){
          FILE* f = fopen("dumplog_sanity.txt", "w");
          rte_pktmbuf_dump(f, m, rte_pktmbuf_pkt_len(m));
          rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, m, rte_pktmbuf_pkt_len(m));
          fclose(f);
          rte_panic("%s\n", reason);
     }
        
}

static inline char *rte_pktmbuf_adj_handmade(struct rte_mbuf *m, uint16_t len)
{
    rte_mbuf_sanity_check_handmade1(m, 1);

     uint16_t diff_of_len_data_len = len - m->data_len;
    if (unlikely(len > m->data_len)){
          os_printf("rte_pktmbuf_adj_handmade: get strange pkt!\n");
          os_printf("len = %"PRIu16", m->data_len = %"PRIu16"\n", len, m->data_len);
          os_printf("m->pkt_len = %"PRIu16", m-> data_off = %"PRIu16"\n", m->pkt_len, m->data_off);
          return NULL;
     }
        
    /* NB: elaborating the addition like this instead of using
     *     += allows us to ensure the result type is uint16_t
     *     avoiding compiler warnings on gcc 8.1 at least */
    uint16_t datalen,dataoff,pktlen;
     datalen = (uint16_t)(m->data_len - len);
    dataoff = (uint16_t)(m->data_off + len);
    pktlen  = (m->pkt_len - len);
     if(0)
          printf("%"PRIu16"%"PRIu16"%"PRIu16"%"PRIu16"",datalen,dataoff,pktlen,diff_of_len_data_len);
     m->data_len = (uint16_t)(m->data_len - len);
    m->data_off = (uint16_t)(m->data_off + len);
    m->pkt_len  = (m->pkt_len - len);
    return (char *)m->buf_addr + m->data_off;
}
```

here is log

```
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: bf loop: ol_flags = 449, port = 0, data_len = 70, pkt_len = 70, nb_segs = 1, buf_len = 2176
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: in loop: ol_flags = 449, port = 0, data_len = 70, pkt_len = 0, nb_segs = 0, buf_len = 2176
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: bf loop: ol_flags = 449, port = 0, data_len = 32, pkt_len = 32, nb_segs = 1, buf_len = 2176
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: in loop: ol_flags = 449, port = 0, data_len = 32, pkt_len = 4294967264, nb_segs = 4294967295, buf_len = 2176
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: before loop: ol_flags = 449, port = 0, data_len = 70, pkt_len = 70, nb_segs = 1, buf_len = 2176
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: after loop: pkt_len = 4294967264, nb_segs = 4294967295
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: last_ptr is not NULL and addr = 0x16dfb3300
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: PANIC in rte_mbuf_sanity_check():
Jul 19 23:22:04 mec cht_mec_dp[3607]: bad nb_segs
```

here is my dump

```
dump mbuf at 0x16e49c9c0, iova=1fae49ca40, buf_len=2176
  pkt_len=70, ol_flags=180, nb_segs=1, in_port=0
  segment at 0x16e49c9c0, data=0x16e49cac0, data_len=70
  Dump data at [0x16e49cac0], len=70
00000000: 34 17 EB 10 37 82 E4 43 4B 79 8C 20 81 00 01 2E | 4...7..CKy. ....
00000010: 08 00 45 00 00 34 B5 22 00 B9 40 11 47 43 0A 1E | ..E..4."..@.GC..
00000020: 04 5B 0A 1E 65 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | .[..e...........
00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
00000040: 00 00 00 00 00 00                               | ......
dump mbuf at 0x16e4a38c0, iova=1fae4a3940, buf_len=2176
  pkt_len=32, ol_flags=1c1, nb_segs=1, in_port=0
  segment at 0x16e4a38c0, data=0x16e4a39e6, data_len=32
  Dump data at [0x16e4a39e6], len=32
00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
00000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
```

Comment: always share paltform, dpdk and nic details. So please share OS, kernel version, DPDK version, NIC and firmware in use. Since you are using multiseg, does the NIC PMD support Multi-seg? and do you enable multiseg in queue setup too?

Comment: I have updated platform information

Comment: in your logs there is weird packet corruption ` for both pkt_len and nb_segs4294967264`. So please add debug code in RX side of the logic as if ((mbuf->nb_segs ==1 ) && (mbuf->next != NULL)) { rte_pktmbuf_dump (stdout, mbuf, mbuf->pkt_len)}. this will ensure if the nic. pmd or application code is culprit.

Comment: were you able to get the packet mbuf dump before running it in your logic? as mentioned there is packet and payload courrption.

Comment: rte_pktmbuf_dump this API also have sanity check,  now I disable sanity check and run again.

Comment: from the logs you shared `bf loop: data_len = 70, pkt_len = 70, nb_segs = 1; in loop: data_len = 70, pkt_len = 0, nb_segs = 0` and `bf loop: data_len = 32, pkt_len = 32, nb_segs = 1; in loop: data_len = 32, pkt_len = 4294967264, nb_segs = 4294967295`. this is very highly `unlikely` it comes from PMD unless there is bug in i40e PMD. hence I have been recommending to dump the packet `if ((mbuf->nb_segs == 1) && (mbuf->next != NULL) && (mbuf->pkt_len < 64))`

Comment: I update my dump in the end of article

Comment: thanks for the update, from the dump logs ` pkt_len=70,  nb_segs=1, ` which means X710 PMD driver is giving the single segment with 70B packet data. But from the processing log as highlighted `data_len = 70, pkt_len = 70, nb_segs = 1; in loop: data_len = 70, pkt_len = 0, nb_segs = 0`, which means either in the `application logic which is not shared` or in the `mbuf_handle logic` there is some corruption or incorrect handling. Can you please check?

Comment: I did not hear back from you so far. As mentioned in earlier comment also, going through the code I noticed something different, in function `rte_mbuf_check_handmade1` inside the do-while loop instead of checking `(nb_segs > 0)` you have restored to `((m = m->next) != NULL)`. I assume you are purposely checking because somehow you feel this should be `NULL` if `nb_segs == 1`. if this is the true intend, I request you modify the question as `why do dpdk mbuf->next is set when mbuf->nb_seg is 1`. This will help a lot in the clarity of the question.